# Qt сохранения в JSON файл

Tags: c++, json, qt

Мое приложение показывает карту и позволяет прокладывать путь. После нажатия на карту, мы видим иконку первого `Waypoint`. После нажатия далее, появляется линия между двумя `Waypoints`. Все координаты показываются в консоли

Мой код для показывания координат в консоли:

```
std::stringstream sstr;
for (int i = 1; i < path->GetPointCount(); i++) {
    Vector lonlatalt;
    path->GetPointLocation(i).GetGeodetic(&lonlatalt);
    sstr << "waypoint";
    sstr << i;
    sstr << " ";
    sstr << lonlatalt.x;
    sstr << " ";
    sstr << lonlatalt.y;
    sstr << " 0.0";
    sstr << std::endl;
}
std::cerr << sstr.str() << std::endl;
```

Вывод получается такой

```
waypoint1: 10.1848, 52.9975
waypoint2: 10.1893, 52.9938
waypoint3: 10.1929, 52.9872
waypoint4: 10.1897, 52.9821
```

Как мне сохранить данный список в `JSON` с учетом того, что один и тот же `waypoint` не должен перезаписывать?

Как бы хотелось чтобы выглядел файл в конце:

```
{
  "waypoint0": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint1": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint2": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint3": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint4": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint5": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint6": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с Json в Qt есть готовые классы - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Вот здесь пример использования - https://habrahabr.ru/post/147952/